# Three.js camera.zoom in does not allow zooming back out

Tags: javascript, html, camera, three.js, zooming

I'm having a Three.js application that has a function which is activated on press of a button and makes some argument calls and then the camera.zoom attribute which zooms the camera to a given factor. But the problem is that when I click the button everything works and the camera gets zoomed in but then i cant zoom out on my scroll wheel. 
Here is a code snippet of the function:

```
function changeCountry(lat, lng) {


  var phi = ((90 - lat) * Math.PI / 180 + PI_HALF);
  target.y = phi;

  var theta = ((180 + lng) * Math.PI / 180 - PI_HALF);
  target.x = theta;
  camera.zoom = 4;
  //camera.position.z = 5200;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();}
```

Comment: I suppose that the first question should be if you are using any of the camera controls. If not, are you attaching any scroll events in order to invoke the change in zoom level? The camera object by itself has no usable controls exposed to the user.

Comment: thanks for the effort. here is a jsfiddle with the whole JavaScript code if you can sort it out. https://jsfiddle.net/wor288fj/  @spac3nerd